# Recipient Name & Required Attendees not matching Outlook Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, calendar, win32com

I am trying to fetch Recipients email address (some are saved contacts, some are in-organization people and remaining are out-of-organization people). I wish to get names and email addresses of all the Required Attendees from a shared calendar. Following is what i have tried so far, but i am not able to get the correct "Recipient" names. Required attendees data is correct, but recipient names dont match.

```
for appointmentItem in restrictedItems:
        Organizer = appointmentItem.Organizer
        Required_Attendees = appointmentItem.RequiredAttendees

        recipient = appointmentItem.Recipients
        for r in recipient:
                recipients_list.append(r)
    
        for rec in recipients_list:     
                rec_nam = rec.name
                email_add = rec.Address
      ##          email_add = rec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress 
                 ## the above command does not give me all email addresses.. 
                 ## ..i dont get out of organization email addresses
```

I am not sure what am i doing wrong! Any help would be appreciated!!

**Issue Faced -**

1. Recipient names not same as Required Attendees
2. Recipient email address not fetched correctly
3. Need to get email address of all people - be it from same organization or outside organization

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: So what is different between what you get and what you expect?

Comment: Ohh i just figured out the solution! The issue was due to multiple loops. The inner loop made my values repeat. I used "name " & "address" in the outer loop, and it worked! However, i only do not get the email addresses of certain recipients, not sure why (maybe they are saved contacts?), ex: "/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=...."